# CameraBridgeViewBase doesnt exist in opencv package

Tags: android, opencv, camera

my activity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2, but eclips doesnt recognize CameraBridgeViewBase:

public class CallActivity extends Activity implements 
CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2

is CameraBridgeViewBase class suppose to be included in the openCV package?
because it doesn't exist in my package.. do i have to write it? or try to download it?
thanks a lot!

Comment: I had that problem but don't remember right now how I fixed. It means your project is not compiling correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It should be in the OpenCV library under org.opencv.android and comes with OpenCV

Have you imported the OpenCV library into your project and referenced it as a library in your projects properties?

What version of OpenCV do you have - here is what mine looks like:

[image]

Comment: I downloaded new version now - 2.4.8. it solved the problem. now i have problems with the necessary definitions. can you recojmend on a good step-by-step explanation of the adjusment of openCV to the workspace? thanks a lot!